# python 2.7 via pymongo does not show the same data that MongoDB shell does

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some test data in a MongoDB collection, which I can inspect using the MongoDB shell:

```
> db
myDatabase
> show collections
cotacoes
> db.cotacoes.find({  "_id": "EURUSD", "trim_data.trimestre": "2020T1", "trim_data.day_data.date": "2020/01/22" }).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "EURUSD",
        "trim_data" : {
                "day_data" : {
                        "date" : "2020/01/22",
                        "hour_data" : {
                                "data" : {
                                        "ASK" : "1.1088",
                                        "BID" : "1.1086"
                                },
                                "time" : "19:46:35"
                        }
                },
                "trimestre" : "2020T1"
        }
}
```

When I try to get the same data using pymongo in Python 2.7, I just get an empty cursor:

```
C:\Files\Python\scripts>python mongotest.py
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000000004039208>
0
```

My python script:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["myDatabase"]
mycol = mydb["cotacoes"]

cursor1 = mydb.mycol.find({  "_id": "EURUSD", "trim_data.trimestre": "2020T1", "trim_data.day_data.date": "2020/01/22" })
print(cursor1)
print(cursor1.count())
```

How can I get the data from the MongoDB database in Python?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Removing "mydb" from the find command was enough to get the expected result:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["myDatabase"]
mycol = mydb["cotacoes"]

cursor1 = mycol.find({  "_id": "EURUSD", "trim_data.trimestre": "2020T1", "trim_data.day_data.date": "2020/01/22" }, {"$snapshot": True})
print(cursor1)
print(cursor1.count())
```

result:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000000003A4DEC8>
1
```